# how to add captcha in a contact form with NO gd

Tags: php, forms, security, captcha, contacts

i'd like some help please.

I'm having a contact form in which i'd like to add some captcha, with **NO GD Library**. I've added some images as a guide but there are static right now. What i'm trying to do is to output in a loop the images that will match with the code (random number) in the hidden field, for example if the random number is "18301" will display the appropriate images for each number, here is my code so far:

```
<label for="captcha">Type the code you see (*):<br />
    <?php (do a loop here){ ?>
<img src="images/0<?php echo $num; ?>.gif" width="18" height="30" />
<?php } ?>  

     <img src="images/00.gif" width="18" height="30" />
         <img src="images/01.gif" width="18" height="30" />
         <img src="images/08.gif" width="18" height="30" />
         <img src="images/03.gif" width="18" height="30" />
         <img src="images/00.gif" width="18" height="30" />
         <img src="images/01.gif" width="19" height="30" /> =</label>
    <span id="spryCaptcha">
    <input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" tabindex="70" />
    <input name="hiddenCode" type="hidden" value="<?php echo rand(000000,999999); ?>"/>
```

How can i make this works so that the correct images will appear each time and checkes the user's input will match to the code he/she sees each time??

Comment: What if the spam bot reads your image filenames?

Comment: Lol, your current implementation rocks

Comment: Static images for a Captcha? NO WAY!!! (or generate millions of captcha with a random name...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should initialize the random number before the loop:

```
<?php
    $random = (string)rand(0,999999);
?>
<label for="captcha">Type the code you see (*):<br />
    <?php for($i=0; $i<strlen($random); $i++){ ?>
        <img src="images/0<?php echo $random{$i}; ?>.gif" width="18" height="30" />
    <?php } ?>  
</label>
<span id="spryCaptcha">
<input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" tabindex="70" />
<input name="hiddenCode" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $random ?>"/>
```

but your should save that in a session and check afterwards (because an hidden field is 0 security):

call `session_start()` on top of your page

```
<?php
    $random = (string)rand(0,999999);
    $_SESSION['captcha'] = $random;
?>
<label for="captcha">Type the code you see (*):<br />
    <?php for($i=0; $i<strlen($random); $i++){ ?>
        <img src="images/0<?php echo $random{$i}; ?>.gif" width="18" height="30" />
    <?php } ?>  
</label>
<span id="spryCaptcha">
<input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" tabindex="70" />
```

and check on next page for your `$_POST['captcha']` against `$_SESSION['captcha']`

still, this is 0 security as image names can be read.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **reCAPTCHA**. It can be used with out GD library.
It loads captcha images from a external service and validates using public key cryptography.
So **NO** internal generation of captcha images. 
Very easy to use.

**E.G:**

**Front End :**

```
<html>
    <body> <!-- the body tag is required or the CAPTCHA may not show on some browsers -->
      <!-- your HTML content -->

      <form method="post" action="verify.php">
        <?php
          require_once('recaptchalib.php');
          $publickey = "your_public_key"; // you got this from the signup page
          echo recaptcha_get_html($publickey);
        ?>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>

      <!-- more of your HTML content -->
    </body>
  </html>
```

**Back End Validation :**

```
<?php
  require_once('recaptchalib.php');
  $privatekey = "your_private_key";
  $resp = recaptcha_check_answer ($privatekey,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

  if (!$resp->is_valid) {
    // What happens when the CAPTCHA was entered incorrectly
    die ("The reCAPTCHA wasn't entered correctly. Go back and try it again." .
         "(reCAPTCHA said: " . $resp->error . ")");
  } else {
    // Your code here to handle a successful verification
  }
  ?>
```

For More info Visit : https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/php